# Android SQLite error on insert

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having a very odd error here

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO course(banner_image,image,subtitle,homepage,short_summary,expected_learning,,new_release,syllabus,title,slug,key,featured,summary,faq,starter,project_description,required_knowledge,project_name,level,full_course_available) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

I have 2 consecutive commas in my query. The problem is that I am building my insert statement using ContentValues class like this

```
private ContentValues createCourseValues(){
    ContentValues courseValues = new ContentValues();
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.SUBTITLE, "Starting Out with Web Serving Technology");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.KEY, "ud171");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.IMAGE, "avc");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.EXPECTED_LEARNING, "You want to build Web services");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.FEATURED, false);
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.PROJECT_NAME, "asd");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.TITLE, "Intro to Backend");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.REQUIRED_KNOWLEDGE, "You have a basic working knowledge ");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.SYLLABUS, "### Forms and Inputs How do web sites security?");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.NEW_RELEASE, false);
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.HOMEPAGE, "https://www.udacity.com/course/" );
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.PROJECT_DESCRIPTION, "");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.FULL_COURSE_AVAILABLE, false);
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.FAQ, "ads");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.BANNER_IMAGE, "xc bv");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.SHORT_SUMMARY, "cvxdf");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.SLUG, "intro-to-backend--ud171");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.STARTER, false);
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.LEVEL, "sdf s");
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.DURATION_IN_HOURS, 504);
    courseValues.put(CourseContract.Course.SUMMARY, "This course presents an overview.");
```

I have run a search and did not find 2 commas anywhere (In fact if it was Java would be pissed with me anyways) I do not understand why there are 2 commas. I feel like there is something deeper in the login that I am not getting.

this is how my insertion goes

```
CourseDBHelper courseDBHelper = new CourseDBHelper(mContext);
    SQLiteDatabase db = courseDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues courseValues = createCourseValues();
    long rowID = db.insertOrThrow(CourseContract.Course.TABLE_NAME, null, courseValues);
    assertTrue(rowID != -1);
```

[Github link here](https://github.com/jennyEckstein/UdacityCoursePicker)

Comment: Where is that method in your GitHub? I've gone through the classes & I can't find it.

Comment: @DanielK app --> src -->androidTest/ java/ com/ jennyeckstein... --> data --> TestDB.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your issue. In your `CourseContract` class the following field is empty:

`public static final String DURATION_IN_HOURS = "";`

I changed it to:

`public static final String DURATION_IN_HOURS = "duration_in_hours";`

and the tests passed.

Comment: thanx great job. totally forgot the value there since its not needed for the json call.

Comment: No problem. Glad I can help.

Answer (score 1):

The pasted Exception about your INSERT does has consecutive commas at `...expected_learning,,new_release...`

Looking in your repo I think maybe you missed passing a value for `CourseContract.Course.DURATION_IN_HOURS` into that insert, making it appear as consecutive commas.

Comment: Yes I know that error has consecutive commas, I posted it. In fact this error comes from insertOrThrow method. This insert is trying to put values in the table but for some reason there are 2 commas. DURATION_IN_HOURS is definately has value passed, its second from the bottom in the code above

Comment: I identified your bug right down to the variable! You didn't have to wait 34 minutes for @Daniel to see my answer and do the work for you. Now that's funny!

Comment: I think @Jenny thought that you were referring to the `createCourseValues()` method because `CourseContract.Course.DURATION_IN_HOURS` does have a value there. That's what I thought you were referring to as well. I went through her DB classes & that's where I found the missing value. Still, I found your answer helpful so I upvoted it.